# How to make a simple 2D pressure vessel drawing in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

Two things:

1) How do I make the semicircle portion of my shape have the same thickness as the straight lines?

2) How do I fill the overall shape with a filling gray colour?

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw (10,0.4) arc (90:270:0.4cm);
\draw (10,0.4) -- (12,0.4);
\draw (10,-0.4) -- (12,-0.4);
\draw (12,0.4) arc (90:-90:0.4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The thickness looks the same. So it might depend on the viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a combination of broken path joins and viewer rendering quality. You can draw it at one shot or put a node instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,fill=blue!30] (0,0.4) arc (90:270:0.4cm)-- (2,-0.4) arc (-90:90:0.4cm)--cycle;
\node[draw=red,fill=red!30,rounded corners=0.4cm,minimum height=0.8cm,minimum width=2.8cm,inner sep=0mm,transform shape] at (1,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with PSTricks just for fun.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,4)
    \pscustom[dimen=m,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange,linewidth=2pt]
    {
        \psarc(2,2){2}{90}{-90}
        \psarc(8,2){2}{-90}{90}
        \closepath
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for comparison, in Metapost you can either draw the path directly using `halfcircle`s or use the `rboxes` library to make rounded boxes.

[image]

```
prologues:=3;outputtemplate:="%j%c.eps";

% A macro that returns the path of a rectangle with rounded ends
vardef vessel(expr width, height) = 
   halfcircle rotated -90 scaled height shifted (+1/2 width,0) --
   halfcircle rotated +90 scaled height shifted (-1/2 width,0) --
   cycle
   enddef;

% for the alternative approach
input rboxes;

beginfig(1);

   % draw the shape centred at the origin
   draw vessel(40,20);

   % in order to fill, draw and label the shapes, you can save them as path variables
   path a,b; 

   a = vessel(55,21) shifted 30 up;
   fill a withcolor .4 blue + .6 white;
   draw a withcolor .8 blue;
   label(btex Vessel $V_1$ etex, center a);

   b = vessel(55,21) shifted 55 up;
   fill b withcolor .4 red + .6 white;
   draw b withcolor .8 red;
   label(btex Vessel $V_2$ etex, center b);

   % or you might prefer the "rboxes" approach
   rboxit.c(btex Vessel $V_3$ etex);
   c.dx = 18; c.dy = 5;
   c.s = 70 up; 
   fill bpath.c withcolor .85 white;
   drawboxed(c);

endfig;
end
```